# How to disable mysqldump command

Tags: linux, mysqldump, rds

I want to disable mysqldump command for all user's including root. As I am taking DB snapshot.

After removing `mysqldump` binary file from `/usr/bin/` location. But is it safe to do so?

Comment: Why would that make `mysqldump` redundant? Did you try to move it from that location to see what breaks? As an example backup tools or scripts could be using it.

Comment: @Seth As per my company requirement no user should execute mysqldump command. I have not found any option to disable mysqldump command. So I remove binary from /use/bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command will prevent anyone, including root, from executing `mysqldump`:

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/bin/mysqldump
```

This command will make `mysqldump` executable again for anyone:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/mysqldump
```

---

You could alternatively remove `/usr/bin/mysqldump`, but it could easily be replaced without your knowledge during a software update.  Or if you end up needing it again, you'd have to reinstall it.

---

### Additional Resources

- [chmod on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)
- [chmod(1) man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)

Comment: Thanks for the point that mysqldmup can be replaced after update.
As after chmod -x /usr/bin/mysqldump I was still able to execute the mysqldump command so I changed command to chmod ogu-x /usr/bin/mysqldump and it works.